# Optimize Mixed API Payloads in REST

Tags: java, rest, serialization, gson, spark-java

I feel like its a standard question with a well defined best practices but for some reason could not find them :).

We have a REST API server (Spark that returns JSON objects) architecture. Currently when ever the client asks for a resource we serialize that object and all the objects it holds. I would like to optimize the payload based on the request it made. Meaning serialize only the fields that are needed by the UI.

For Example:

```
<GET> /users/<userId> - return all the user with Address object
<GET> /users - return all the users with out the Address (just the top level)
<GET> /transactions/<businessId> - returns all the transactions with User object that contains only the userId and the user name.
```

I am familiar the marking a field as `transient` but I am looking for something more fine grained then this.

One option I had in mind was to use [com.google.gson.TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for every call, but I was hoping there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Yes!! thanks for fixing

Comment: Looks like Spark offers [Response Transformers](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response-transformer) that may be useful to produce the desired output. This seems to be similar to the [interceptor concept of JAX-RS](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e9805). You could also declare custom document types, i.e. one for user data including addresses and one without, though not every client will be able to handle these custom document types correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned GSON, you should use [ExclusionStrategy](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html).